# Normal map baking of parts that are close to each other(intersecting cage)

Tags: workflow, normal-map

High poly toes(where is the problem. They are too close to each other):
[image]

Low poly(shrinkwrap on surface dist: 0.0):
[image]

Cage(0.001) 2 toes are already intersecting:
[image]

If I reduce cage extrusion distance then it's not gonna cover high poly mesh. And I will have to add more polygons(which I don't want to do since only 3 toes already have 528 triangles with). I've tried to separate toes from the mesh(on another model similar situation) and bake step by step. But in the result I had a visible seams in normal map.

So I see a 3 solutions: 1)Spread toes(difficult on high poly). 2)Increase poly count on low poly to reduce the distance of cage extrusion(don't want to have too many polygons). 3)Somehow separate toes and bake one by one(just twice) but what about the seam?

Are there other ways to deal with such parts while baking normal map?

Comment: Hi. It's not clear what you exactly did to bake the normal map. What do you mean by "*Cage(0.001)*"? Do you use the *Extrusion* value in the bake settings with 2 objects (high to low poly) *-or-* a cage object and high-poly to low-poly (that's 3 objects)?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply! It's to show that baking with Extrusion value = 0.001 is going to self-intersect. Basically it's same low poly but just shrink/flatten(edit mode/tool) with value 0.001. It's seems that this tool pushes all faces along normals with value that you enter and this can be used as a cage object(I might be wrong). I do it before baking to check if parts that are close to each other will intersect. Cage object gives you an option to push some parts manually a bit further/closer but if I use just extrusion it's going to be the same as in screenshot.

Comment: I just thought that I might try to shrink/flatten manually and use cage object. hope it's not gonna add any "baking artifacts"!

Comment: Works! So I will just manually shrink/flatten in edit mode verts of self intersected parts and will use that model as a cage. didn't notice any artifacts!